# How can I use 2 cell validations on the same range?

Tags: regex, validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I'm writing a database from a questionnaire, and I need certain cells to show a warning when another cell is blank and when is not certain values (like a drop-down list), how can I do that?

I'm actually using `=not(isblank($AU2))` for the blank part, but now I need the drop-down list or something like that

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DcIImAnqY_SUq6HKxmeEeAt2c4hYt65lfO9apLRskjU/edit?usp=sharing

This is an example, I need tho write data on B when A is 1, and it has to be any of the numbers on sheet "lists" D1 (Column B).

Comment: And what if I need a double condition, like, if A2=1 and B2 is between 2 and 4 then is a valid entry on C

Comment: `=(A2=1)*(B2>=2)*(B2<=4)`

Answer (score 0):

custom formula would be:

```
=(A2=1)*(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(B2), "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, INDIRECT("Lists!B2:B")&"$")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That kinda works, but it doesn't reject numbers that contains the characters of the list, for example, 10 is not rejected because it has a "1".

Comment: @JulioAndrésLeivaValdés I see... try now - answer updated